# Deleting all div children from a parent without a for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code in my javascript:

```
for (var a = 0; a < cnt; a++) {
    var element = document.getElementById("button" + a).getElementsByTagName("div");

     for (index = element.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
          element[index].parentNode.removeChild(element[index]);
     }

     $("#button" + a).append("Some large html data");
}
```

I am deleting all the children from parent id "button0","button1"... and so on, which are divs.
and then appending new data to those parents.

However, this particular piece of code takes a long time to execute when the cnt is more than 200, which it usually is. How will I be able to speed it up? Is there an alternative way to delete all children divs without going through each of it?

Comment: it will be better if you add a fiddle

Comment: Maybe this document.getElementById("button" + a).innerHTML = "";

Comment: please share html structur and jsfiddle link if possible

Comment: ("button"+a) parent divs would have children with divs<div> and<img> image elements, I only want to delete the ones that are div elements

Comment: Could you add a class on your button ?

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vtefL453/

Comment: You can visually delete it with CSS. You give the old divs some class name and then you add a class name to the parant container of all elements with #button<i>. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/awkq8vyr/

Comment: If you are using jQuery then you can achieve the desired results with one line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : You can use children selector to remove them, no need to iterate through children.

```
for (var a = 0; a < cnt; a++) {
    //remove div elements inside button
    $("#button"+a+" > div").remove();

     $("#button" + a).append("Some large html data");
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vtefL453/6/)**

IF you can have particular class to button `div` then you can get rid of `for` loop.

Lets say `class="buttonDiv"` is assigned to all button `div`, for example

```
<div id="button0" class="buttonDiv">
```

Now your jQuery script to remove child `div` will be like

```
$('div.buttonDiv').each(function(){
  $(this).children("div").remove();
  $(this).append("Some large html data");
});
```

**[DEMO with Class](http://jsfiddle.net/vtefL453/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="main">
   <p>hello p1</p>
   <p>hello p2</p>
   <span> hello world this is span </span>
</div>

$('.main p').remove();    // any number of depths
$('.main > p').remove();    // immediate children
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to delete them, but I don't know how much faster it will be. Under the covers it has to do pretty much the same work:

```
for (var a = 0; a < cnt; a++) {
    $("#button" + a + " div").remove().end().append("Some large html data");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you just add one class to all the buttons you want to remove the children of. Lets say you add the class `button` to all of them. Then you could just do this:

```
$('.button > div').remove(); // Removes all direct children divs of the .button element.
```

Or

```
$('.button div').remove(); // Removes all divs inside the `.button` element.
```